# Migrate existing hbase tables with namespace to Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I follow https://phoenix.apache.org/namspace_mapping.html to do

- set `phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled` enabled in hbase-site.xml

When I use `./psql.py node1:2181 -m 'loh'.'traffic'` to migrate.

get error

```
org.apache.phoenix.schema.TableNotFoundException: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=LOH.TRAFFIC
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PMetaDataImpl.getTableRef(PMetaDataImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection.getTable(PhoenixConnection.java:583)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.getTable(PhoenixRuntime.java:449)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.UpgradeUtil.upgradeTable(UpgradeUtil.java:1823)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.main(PhoenixRuntime.java:264)
```

"loh:traffic" is existing in hbase, why the table not found? Why can't not create table and get data auto like **system** namespace.

```
hbase(main):005:0> list
TABLE
SYSTEM:CATALOG
SYSTEM:FUNCTION
SYSTEM:LOG
SYSTEM:MUTEX
SYSTEM:SEQUENCE
SYSTEM:STATS
loh:traffic
7 row(s)
Took 0.5282 seconds
=> ["SYSTEM:CATALOG", "SYSTEM:FUNCTION", "SYSTEM:LOG", "SYSTEM:MUTEX", "SYSTEM:SEQUENCE", "SYSTEM:STATS", "loh:traffic"]
```

phoenix

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:node1:2181> !tables
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
| TABLE_CAT  | TABLE_SCHEM  | TABLE_NAME  |  TABLE_TYPE   | REMARKS  | TYPE_NAME  | SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME  | REF_GENERATION  | INDEX_STATE  | IMMUTABLE_ROWS  | SALT_BUCKETS  | MULTI_TENANT  | VIEW_S |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
|            | SYSTEM       | CATALOG     | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false         |        |
|            | SYSTEM       | FUNCTION    | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false         |        |
|            | SYSTEM       | LOG         | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | 32            | false         |        |
|            | SYSTEM       | SEQUENCE    | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false         |        |
|            | SYSTEM       | STATS       | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false         |        |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
```